# calculate AUC from recall and precision

Tags: matlab, data-mining

I Have Precisions and Recalls. I want to Plot ROC Curve and calculate AUC.Unfortunately I not done with MATLAB.

Comment: I am not sure you can get a unique ROC curve given only precision and recall. You need the actual rates. i.e. true positive, false positive, true negative, etc.. You can check out [this paper](https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~page/rocpr.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You need true positive rates and false positive rates, not precision and recall.

I can't help you with MATLAB. Use open-source like sklearn instead, MATLAB is dead.

Comment: I have true positive and false positive and etc too.

Comment: Can I do this with just one experiment or need to do a lot of experiments?

Comment: Assuming that you are evaluating a *ranking*, you get an ROC AUC or PR AUC curve for a *single* ranking. There are other scenarios, where you do e.g. a parameter sweep and plot the curve based on these parameters, that may require many experiments.